# created Unbound server, can dig but getaddrinfo() fails

Tags: dns, unbound

I was able to start an unbound server and now can succecifuly use the `dig` command but can't use any other command due to name resolution failing.

```
$ dig one.one.one.one

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> one.one.one.one
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37768
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;one.one.one.one.       IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
one.one.one.one.    286 IN  A   1.1.1.1
one.one.one.one.    286 IN  A   1.0.0.1

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: ::1#53(::1)
;; WHEN: Mon May 23 15:37:34 JST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 76

$ ping one.one.one.one
ping: one.one.one.one: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Answer (score 0):

needed to add loopback address to /etc/resolv.conf